# How to measure progress of loading json file from axios call?

Tags: javascript, axios

In order to measure progress, I'm thinking about doing these two things while making axios call:

1. get file size while making call to json file
2. get percentage of file downloaded out of the file size from network tab

So far I just have this where I can get the data but I need some way to get the metadata behind it (the information in the network console like file size, amount downloaded so far)

```
const request = axios.get('/data');

request.then((response) => {


}
```

Or is there another way of measuring progress?

Answer (score 5):

you just need to pass in a configuration object with the onUploadProgress function:

```
let progress = 0;
const request = axios.post('/data', {
    onUploadProgress: function(event) {
       progress = Math.round((event.loaded * 100) / event.total);
    }
});

request.then((response) => {
    //
}
```

then use the progress variable as you wish.

Note: If using a `get` request use `onDownloadProgress` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030158/can-we-use-ondownloadprogress-from-axios-for-loading-api)

Comment: Please note that your code will not work. "onUploadProgress" works for post/ upload requests not get requests. I think you mean "onDownloadProgress"

Comment: oh ok, then change the get to post :D