# Can we use onDownloadProgress from axios for loading API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I need to create a progress bar for loading API in a react project using axios, and I discovered the `onDownloadProgress` function for this, but I don't know if we can use it for get information like loading percentage for example or if it only for files download?

So I don't sure if we can get information about API loading with this function?

I tried to implement this function in my code :

```
componentWillMount() {
  axios.get('https://guillaumeduclos.fr/jd-portfolio/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
  .then(response => {
    axios.onDownloadProgress = (progressEvent) => {
      let percentCompleted = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total );
      console.log(percentCompleted);
    }
    this.setState({
      datas: response.data[0].acf.project_illustration.url,
      loading: false
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if(error.response) {
      console.log(error.responderEnd);
    }
  });
}
```

The `console.log()` is not display.

Answer (score 8):

You need to pass the `onDownloadProgress` in as an option.
It will print out "Infinity" because of the lengthComputable.

Here is a post regarding that issue: [JQuery ajax progress via xhr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502943/jquery-ajax-progress-via-xhr/22504560#22504560)

```
componentWillMount() {
axios.get('https://guillaumeduclos.fr/jd-portfolio/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', {
  onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
    let percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
    console.log(progressEvent.lengthComputable)
    console.log(percentCompleted);
  }
})
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({
      datas: response.data[0].acf.project_illustration.url,
      loading: false
    })
  }).catch(error => {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.responderEnd);
    }
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

progressEvent.total is undefined in json